# Is there any C# syntactic sugar to both test for null and return a value in one shot?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if there's any syntactic sugar in C# that will let you both check an item for whether it's null or not *and* retrieve a value from it if not null in one statement.

Here's some example code that illustrates what I'm trying to get at:

```
public class A 
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public B SubItem { get; set }
}

public class B 
{
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

static class Program 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        // object with a subitem - subitem is not null.
        A variable1 = new A 
        {
            Value = "This has a subitem.",
            SubItem = new B 
            {
                Value2 = "This is the subitem."
            }
        }

        // object without a subitem = subitem is null.
        A variable2 = new A
        {
            Value = "This has no subitem."
        }

        // object with a subitem, but the subitem's value is empty, so should be treated as null for purposes of string output
        A variable3 = new A
        {
            Value = "This has an empty subitem and should be treated the same as a null subitem.",
            SubItem = new B 
            {
                Value2 = ""
            }
        }

        // Use cases

        // ok, because subItem is not null - prints the subitem's value.
        Console.WriteLine("The first variable's subitem: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable1.SubItem.Value2) ? "(null)" : variable1.SubItem.Value2)); 

        // ok, because subitem is not null, but produces "(null)" as expected since the subitem has no value
        Console.WriteLine("The third variable's subitem: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable3.SubItem.Value2) ? "(null)" : variable3.SubItem.Value2)); 

        // succeeds, but always evaluates to "(null)" for every item even if subitem is not null and contains a value.
        Console.WriteLine("The first variable's subitem: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable1.SubItem?.Value2) ? "(null)" : variable1.SubItem.Value2));
        Console.WriteLine("The second variable's subitem: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable2.SubItem?.Value2) ? "(null)" : variable2.SubItem.Value2)); 
        Console.WriteLine("The third variable's subitem: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable3.SubItem?.Value2) ? "(null)" : variable3.SubItem.Value2));

        // fails with a NullReferenceException - this is the problem case.
        Console.WriteLine("The second variable's subitem: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable2.SubItem.Value2) ? "(null)" : variable2.SubItem.Value2)); 

        // ugly solution here
        string secondVariableSubItem;
        if (variable2.SubItem != null) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable2.SubItem.Value2) 
            {
                secondVariableSubItem = "(null)";
            }
            else 
            {
                secondVariableSubItem = variable2.SubItem.Value2;
            }
        }
        else {
            secondVariableSubItem = "(null)";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The second variable's subitem: " + secondVariableSubItem); // works as expected, but ugly

        // condensed, but still kind of ugly
        Console.WriteLine("The second variable's subitem: " + ( variable2.SubItem != null ? ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable2.SubItem.Value2) ? "(null)" : variable2.SubItem.Value2 ) : "(null)" );
    }
}
```

The ugly solution works but requires doing a few things I don't like - first of all, having to repeat the value that should be given if the string is null or empty (the object might not be null, but the string still might be), and just the fact that it requires so many lines of code to express this situation, and thus it's less readable.

I would have expected that the `?` modifier would have worked, but for some reason the IsEmptyOrNull method always returns true when you use it, even if the object is not null and contains a value.

The condensed version is a little better but still has the issue of requiring the default value to be listed twice. It could be set in a variable, but that just starts bringing you back to a lot of messy code.

Possible, or do I need to stick with the ugly method?

Comment: yes, `??` tests for null and returns itself, when not null. `value = object ?? "Value is now String";` when object is null.

Comment: What the type of subItem? Maybe an extension method: variable2.SubItem?.getValue()

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("The second variable's subitem: " + (variable2.SubItem.Value2 ?? "(null)"));` This still causes a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Yes you're looking for `string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable2?.SubItem?.Value2 ?? null)`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("The second variable's subitem: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(variable2.SubItem.Value2 ?? null) ? "(null)" : variable2.SubItem.Value2 ));` Still causes NullReferenceException. Seems like the coalesce operator doesn't help, since the runtime tries to go straight to "SubItem.Value2", which is impossible since SubItem is null, and throws the exception.

Comment: Assuming the sample you provided is applicable to your actual problem, I'd use a recursive static method on your class. But that'd be assuming that you merge class A and Class B since they are the same; still, even if you can't use recursion, a static method that performs the evaluation you want will be nice in case you ever need to modify it.

Comment: You dont need null-coalescing operator, just the null-conditional operator `variable2?.SubItem?.Value2`

Comment: your sample code is way too long

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeOtherClass Class { get; }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}

public static class SomeClassExtension
{
    public static string IsNullOrEmpty(this SomeClass obj)
    {
        // you can use string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Class?.Test) too but just for you understand
        if(obj.Class == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Class.Test))
            return "(null)";

        return obj.Class.Test;
    }
}
```

Example with null:

```
// Will return (null) because SomeOtherClass is null
SomeClass c = new SomeClass();

string a = c.IsNullOrEmpty();
```

Example with some value:

```
SomeClass class2 = new SomeClass();
class2.Class = new SomeOtherClass();
class2.Class.Test = "value";

// will return the "value"
string b = class2.IsNullOrEmpty();
```

Maybe you can do something like that. Assuming that I understand your problem correctly and you want to read the same variable in more than one object.

Answer (score 0):

Use null coalescing `??` operator in this way to get what you want. For `Value2`

```
variable2?.SubItem?.Value2
```

will return `null` if `variable2 == null`, `variable2.SubItem == null`, or `variable2.SubItem.Value2 == null`, otherwise it will return Value2.

Wrapping the whole thing in a `IsNullOrWhitespace` check

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(variable2?.SubItem?.Value2)
```

Comment: Why do you need the null coalescing operator to coalesce with null? I mean, if `variable2.SubItem.Value2` is null, `variable2?.SubItem?.Value2` will return null already...